# Unusual IC package in Li-po charging circuit

Tags: identification, boost, converter, qfn

I came across this IC package on a Chinese Li-po battery charging circuit PCB. It appears to be a type of boost converter/charge controller. It looks like a 3-sided QFN 3x3 with 16 pins. No logo or part number - only a lot code. Has anyone seen this package before?

[image: Photo of IC package]

Comment: What is your question except that if anyone hase seen this before? What is this part? The package name? something else?

Comment: It's an open question. If anyone has any information to offer it would be appreciated. Ideally I would like to ID the chip and locate a datasheet.

Comment: Then please state it explicitly. SE is not for "open questions", these are usually closed as too broad or lacking details.

Comment: You can close this then. Sorry I ruined your day.

Comment: The OEM solder-job looks like it could have benefitted from a little more flux. :)  If it does have sense pads underneath, I'd be suspicious.

Comment: You aren't ruining anyone's day, it's a simple request to keep questions on the site on-topic.

Answer (score 4):

From the application, I'm betting it is or incorporates a current sensor with the sense pads completely underneath the package like so:

[image: Si8512]

Photo is a Si8512 from Digikey.

Comment: Excellent find! Do you call the capsule anything special?

Comment: It's billed as a "12-pin QFN" on the datasheet (https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Silicon%20Laboratories%20PDFs/SI85xx_C_Rev2012_DS.pdf).  That's the only one like that that I can find in a quick search; most other similar sensors have a wettable flank (little stub that reaches the edge of the package) to make inspection easier but it looks like your guys are either x-raying or just crossing their fingers.